# developer access token dialogflow

Tags: access, бот, token, искусственный-интеллект, dialogflow

Как найти где находится 33-значный developer access token и client access token в Dialogflow?

Answer (score 0):

Dialogflow Enterprise поддерживает только версии v2 или v2beta1 API Dialogflow, которые для аутентификации полагаются на Google Cloud IAM, а не на старый токен доступа разработчика. См. Страницу «Настройка аутентификации» в руководстве по переходу с Dialogflow V1 на V2 и обзор аутентификации Google Cloud.